# Why can't I match the string?

Tags: bash, shell

my code:

```
# (1)
#result='/usr/bin/which: no commandName in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/wks/.local/bin:/home/wks/bin)'

# (2)
result=`which commandName`

echo $result

reg='commandName'

if [[ $result =~ $reg  ]]
then echo "exit"
else echo "not exit"
fi
```

If I use code (2),  will print `not exit`, but if I use code (1), it will print `exit`.

But the `which commandName` will get the same content in my PC, it is

`/usr/bin/which: no commandName in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/wks/.local/bin:/home/wks/bin)`

so what is the reason for the different behavior?

Comment: `` are used to execute another command like: `var=\`ls /home/\``. What is `->(2):` suppose to do, I get command not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your code (2), `result` ends up being empty.

`/usr/bin/which: no commandName ...` is an error message and thus written to stderr. Backticks (as in `` `which ...` ``) only capture standard output, not errors.

If you want to capture both stdout and stderr, do something like

```
result=$(which commandName 2>&1)
```

Comment: its  right ,   with  echo $result  ,   I did see a line of white   space

Answer (score -1):

in bash, use in the line following which variable $? to check how the last command ended, which is "which" and the second test do only if the return code is 0, code 1 means that the command failed.

```
res=`which asasa`
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
#etc.
```

Comment: I know this works ,  but  I wonder why the code I mentioned doesn't work

Comment: because the result contains a string "/ usr / bin / which: no commandName in (/ usr / local / bin: / usr / bin: / usr / local / sbin: / usr / sbin: / home / wks /. local / bin: / home / wks / bin)" not the string "commandName"  as you expect.

Comment: but i use  =~ .it means  Whether  the string  contains the right string

Comment: w bash  =~ means stringA does not correspond to stringB

Comment: but  if i  use code (1)   give the value "/ usr / bin / which: no commandName in...." to $result ,  it  will  print "exit"   ,it means contains

Comment: bash does not work like it would just like it's in the documentation.
in addition =~ works only in [[]], better use != or ==

Comment: I see what you used, [[]] does not have a direct connection to your question.
the problem is to use = ~ in a different sense than in the documentation, it is not just checking whether they differ.

Comment: I confused the operators ~= i =~ in the comments, Sorry. The method with $? in response, it is correct and simpler than stream redirection stderr. In my debut, `which notCommand` returns nothing. Not everyone has the same configurations.